# Why i'm getting "Runtime Error: NZEC" for a simple code

Tags: python, runtime-error

It was a simple problem but I’m getting NZEC.

The code has to print the inputs until we got the value 42. The time we got this number(42) we must stop taking inputs. The problem link is here: https://www.codechef.com/LRNDSA01/problems/TEST

The code I have written is as shown below:

```py
while True:
    n = int(input())
    if n != 42:
        print(n)
    else:
        break
```

Comment: couldn't reproduce the problem. Are you selecting python3 while uploading code? I pasted the same code, it was accepted

Comment: yes, I'm using python 3.6

Comment: are you pressing run or submit? If you are pressing run, you need to click custom input and add their input data. CodeChef does not use the test case automatically